# Georgian language in OCR

Tags: ocr, georgian

I have a problem with converting JPG files containing images of texts to the text files. I tried ABBYY's OCR SDK and some other sources of OCR but none of them contains Georgian language.

Could you please tell me if there is any OCR source which could be used for Georgian language?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3):

[Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3) is fully trainable; you can train it for your language. Tools like [jTessBoxEditor](http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html) can be very useful in editing the box files.